# Interfacing PS2 keyboard

Tags: windows, interface, controller, keyboard

I recently received from a friend a cash register keyboard, however, it was just that, no drivers, no documentation, nothing, I've never did anything like this, so any directions would be really appreciated, the [circuit is fairly simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu3z6.jpg)

I tried reading the inscriptions on the controller, but, it is a little unreadable, all that I could make out of it was "__BC2489_-2_", I can also read "1213", "05 CHI" and "___615626", I assume the first one to be the model, however, I can't seem to find anything with just this partial reading. 
Contacting the manufacturer I was able to get the hex codes sent by the keyboard, which can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlKvy.png).

Connecting it makes no device-connected sound as Windows usually does, does this means something may be wrong with it, or Windows just doesn't recognize it as there are no drivers? To be fair, I don't even remember if it makes any noise at all for PS/2 devices. So, how should I proceed now? Is there a way to simply read from the PS/2 port or anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a PS 2 Keyboard you have to plug it in before booting the OS. It’s not Plug and Play able. (It won’t make a special sound)

Comment: Oh, ok, back to the old times, I forgot about that part. So, considering it has an integrated controller, would just that be enough to get it working?(Of course, aside setting the hex codes to actual functions.)